# separating buttons so they don't overlap

Tags: html

This is a really simple question, but I can't find any answers on Google.

I used `<div style=\"margin-left: 44px;\">` to move a button to the left, what div do I need to move the buttons down? They are currently overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "div" element is a block!  Try putting your buttons inside divs as follows:

```
<div style="margin:20px;">Button</div>
```

Or if you just want to set the bottom margin, you can use:

```
style="margin-bottom:20px";
```

Or set them all together, in the order top,right,bottom,left

```
style="margin: 0 0 20px 44px;"
```

Last, try setting margins within the Buttons themselves.  If they are anchors, you can try this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" style="display:block; margin:20px; overflow:hidden;">BUTTON</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use positioning instead of margins, if you want to position divs all around

example:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:44px;">
 Content
</div>
```

example 2:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:10px;left:44px;">
 Content
</div>
```

more about positioning:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp